# passing rows of dataframe as argument to a function in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am trying to pass columns of a dataframe as arguments to function in row wise manner but I am ending in an error.
I tried to do by loop as my actual dataframe and function requires loop only.

```
def sum(x, y, z):
     return x + y + z
Input = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2,3], 'B': [10, 20,22],'C':[4,5,6]})
output = pd.DataFrame({'output': [15, 27,31]})

##What I tried, but this tells me it needs more arguments
for a in Input:
    sum(a)
```

Could anyone help me, as I need to iterate all the rows of dataframe as in argument to a function so in short number of columns of dataframe is equal to number of arguments in functions

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Input.apply(lambda row : sum(row.A, row.B, row.C), axis=1)
```

axis = 1, mean on column level. can refer at [pandas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)
It asks for more arguments because it does not know which column you want to do operation.